# Similar series converging to $-1$

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series

Let $g(n)\in\mathbb{C}$ it is known that:

- $g(n)\ne 0$
- $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}{g(n)} = 0 $
- $\sum\limits_{n=2}^{\infty}{ n^\alpha g(n)} = -1$
- $\sum\limits_{n=2}^{\infty}{ n^{-\alpha} g(n)} = -1$

Is it true that necessarily $\alpha = 0$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  For $n \ge 4$ let $g(n)$ be something that goes to zero fast enough so $\sum_{n=4}^\infty n^\alpha g(n)$ converges for all $\alpha$, like $g(n)=e^{-n}$  Given any $\alpha$ you can compute $G(\alpha)=\sum_{n=4}^\infty n^\alpha g(n)$  Now you just have two simultaneous equations $$2^\alpha g(2)+3^\alpha g(3)+G(\alpha) =-1\\2^{-\alpha} g(2)+3^{-\alpha} g(3)+G(-\alpha)=-1$$
which you can solve for $g(2),g(3)$

Generally speaking, convergence only regulates what happens "near infinity".  We can play with early terms of a series to make the sum anything we want.

Comment: What if $g(2)$ and $g(3)$ can not be independent variables. I mean, what if you are stuck to the terms such us $g(2)=e^{-2}$ and $g(3)=e^{-3}$?

Comment: Your question asked about any $g(n)$, so I get to pick.  If you specify a $g(n)$ you can compute the sum for any $\alpha$.  Whether you can get the sum to come out $-1$ for any $\alpha$ depends on the $g(n)$ you specify.